# How to match multiple condition in if else

Tags: scala, if-statement

I have 3 variables like below, and I want the result as first priority is return x, if x is blank then return y, if x and y both blank then return z.

below is my code, but this is not working.

```
val x = "1"
val y = "2"
val z = "3"

val result = {
var res = "
if (x == "") y else x
else if (y == "") z
}
For result First priority is to x and if x = "" then y, if y also "" then return z
```

Please help

Comment: When asking a question, instead of saying something "is not working", say whether you're getting an error message, other unexpected behavior, or what. If there is an error, paste in the complete text of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning Integer value to variables & Checking empty string if condition. `` Comparing values of types Int and String using `==' will always yield false ``

Please check below code.

```
// For variables of type string.
if(x != "") x else if (y != "") y else z
```

```
scala> val x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> val y = 2
y: Int = 2

scala> val z = 3
z: Int = 3

scala> if(x != "") x else if (y != "") y else z // This will give result if variables are type string. but if it is int type checking this way give you wrong values.
<console>:30: warning: comparing values of types Int and String using `!=' will always yield true
       if(x != "") x else if (y != "") y else z
            ^
<console>:30: warning: comparing values of types Int and String using `!=' will always yield true
       if(x != "") x else if (y != "") y else z
                                ^
res8: Int = 1


scala> if (!x.isNaN) x else if(!y.isNaN) y else z // Check this way
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, Sorry for my mistake, variables are String not int.

Comment: If  your variables are string , You can use this - if(x != "") x else if (y != "") y else z & updated answer.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it helps to resolve issue ?

Comment: Hi Srinivas, jut I tested the above solution, its working fine but incase first two variables are blank, its returning last vriable like : Success(08122019111841), can we return value without Success()  ?

Comment: I didn't get how success came into this .. can you please give me your input ?

Comment: It was success(value) as I was using Try(......Substring value), So got, now remoed Try and getting alue without success.